# Завершение потока

Tags: winapi, права, процесс

Требуется завершить поток другого процесса, зная `ThreadID` потока.
Функции `TerminateThread` нужно передать `hThread`, который следовало бы
получить с помощью `OpenThread` с параметром `THREAD_TERMINATE`. Однако, 
при вызове функции `OpenThread` возникает ошибка

> Access violation

Как правильно завершить поток? Сторонние утилиты с этой задачей
успешно справляются. Значит, это возможно.

Comment: Какая операционная система?

Comment: Покажи как ты это делаешь? (кусок кода)

Comment: Windows XP SP3.

Comment: Ошибка Access violation получена через GetLastError или она просто возникает на этапе выполнения?

Comment: В документации пишется: If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call GetLastError. Возвращаемое функцией OpenThread значение - NULL. Что значит "просто возникает на этапе выполнения", не понял.

Comment: Что возвращает функция GetLastError?

Comment: ERROR_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Comment: Nicolas Chabanovsky, я не хотел ограничиваться только средствами Win32 API. Функции NT Native API меня тоже устраивают.

Comment: @Splen, код (номер) ошибки можешь назвать?

Comment: @Splen, где ты вообще взял ERROR_ACCESS_VIOLATION? Её нет в списке ошибок.

Comment: Посмотрите подробнее описание функции OpenThread: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684335%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Первый параметр dwDesiredAccess проверяется на предмет соответствия запрошенных прав доступа со структурой SecurityDescriptor потока. Судя по всему, Вы получаете Access Violation, потому что поток защищен от доступа с привилегией THREAD_TERMINATE.

Comment: Понятно, что не хватает прав. Тем не менее, стороние утилиты с этим справляются. Вопрос в том, каких именно прав и как их получить.